# Firebase Messaging unregister notification for read_timeout failed

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to send a notification from one device to another device to let the user know there is a waiting message for him.

When I was trying to catch and handle the RemoteMessage this is what console prints. It happens on iOS physical devices.

That function works perfectly before but now it is impossible to send notification to other user over the device, client side.

Function overview:

```
  static Future<void> sendNotificationToOtherUser(
      String title, String body, String token) async {
    final headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization':
          'key={I hide KEY but I assure you there is nothing wrong with key}'
    };
    List<String> list = List();
// token is not null
    list.add(token);
    final postUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    final data = {
      "registration_ids": list,
      "notification": {
        "title": '$title',
        "body": '$body',
      },
    };

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(postUrl),
        body: json.encode(data),
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
        headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // it prints 200 so works perfectly
      print(response.body);
      print('test ok push CFM');
      return true;
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      print(' CFM error');
      // on failure do sth
      return false;
    }
  }
```

It seems everything works but other device cannot catch Notification and shows it due to error I put below.
Error:

```
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C6.1 216.58.212.42:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C6.1 216.58.212.42:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
```

Libraries:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.4
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.1
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0
```

Flutter SDK version:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale
    en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at /Users/user/development/flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (4 weeks ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3
```

Comment: Found out the problem. I need to refresh FCM token inside Firestore in order to get notifications because that token was no longer valid.

Comment: Were you receiving push notification atleast? I have the same problem but I am receiving push notifications and they are being displayed but I cant access the RemoteMessage on the onMessage Listener or even the background listener. I have been looking for a solution for some time, would really appreciate your response on this.

Comment: Did you try to force to refresh FCM token? I solved it by doing that. @Maz

Comment: Yes we found the issue, I was using getAPNSToken instead of getToken. We are using Django and its packages to send notification. I dont know how this is related but that was the fix. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I think issue solved,summarized as the following:

1. Use getToken() instead of getAPNSToken(). Using Firebase Messaging SDK to send messages, only tokens from getToken() will valid.
2. Device token renews itself if one of the following happens:
   (1).The app deletes Instance ID
   (2).The app is restored on a new device
   (3).The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
   (4).The user clears app data.

Reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client for detail.

3. you can also try Messaging experiment to send a testing notification to a specific ios device, by doing this, you can easily decide what may goes wrong.

Answer (score -5):

If you want to hide these errors do this:

1. From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme
2. Left item "Run" -> Tab "Arguments"
3. Add Environment Variable:

> OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681040

Comment: This is not a solution. All this does is turn off all debug logging, including the stuff that is useful.